# Remove text from black and white photo

Tags: gimp, photo-editing, mac

How do I remove the text from this image please?

I have tried using clone tool but it is very messy. I have Gimp on a Mac.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Wow. I'd love to know exactly where that was*. I used to live (35 years ago) in Oulton, right next door to Woodlesford. I don't recall ever seeing that on my travels, presumably long demolished.

Gimp has a plugin called Resynthesizer, which can be used as a 'heal' tool. It's included in the build if you use the version of Gimp from https://www.partha.com which one of the senior members here (Billy Kerr) pointed me to just recently. I certainly feels more Mac-like than the regular Gimp build & seems to be a good bit faster at some operations.

[image]

Here's what I got from Gimp - at which I'm not particularly practised. You could probably do better with a bit more effort.

[image]

In Photoshop you'd use Content-Aware Fill to do a similar job

[image]

Just for fun, I had a quick go at removing some of the the vignette & "de-crunching" it a bit… It's not perfect, but the original is very crunchy.

[image]

*Now solved - [Google Maps link](https://www.google.com/maps/@53.7423174,-1.4530725,3a,75y,104.26h,90t/data=!3m7!1e1!3m5!1sjAX_n8jlU1dVPDxY4qcAuw!2e0!6s%2F%2Fgeo1.ggpht.com%2Fcbk%3Fpanoid%3DjAX_n8jlU1dVPDxY4qcAuw%26output%3Dthumbnail%26cb_client%3Dmaps_sv.tactile.gps%26thumb%3D2%26w%3D203%26h%3D100%26yaw%3D155.25063%26pitch%3D0%26thumbfov%3D100!7i16384!8i8192) - nothing left any more :\
<sup>… with apologies to the rest of the world who won't give a d@mn where the picture was taken ;)</sup>

Comment: I was about to write an answer, but you beat me to it.  +1 anyway ;)

Comment: Maybe just a note here, if installing Partha's MacGIMP seems like too much trouble, or if you are using GIMP on Windows/Linux, you can just download the plugin from the post in the gimp-forum here: https://www.gimp-forum.net/Thread-Resynthisizer-Heal-Selection-Runtime-Error?pid=12687#pid12687 - and put the Python files in your GIMP plugins folder, and restart GIMP.

Comment: @BillyKerr - It's actually dead simple - it's literally drag & drop to the Apps folder, there's no 'install' process at all, it's self-contained.

Comment: Yeah, Partha also has something similar for the Windows version, those marked as "Portable" for Windows. It's basically a zip you just extract to anywhere you want.

Comment: Many thanks Tetsujin. Now on this page. https://newwoodlesford.xyz/gallery/light-industries/glenoit/

Comment: Oh, I must have driven past there hundreds of times. My folks lived in Crossgates, so I'd go down Bullerthorpe Lane behind Templenewsham & up Aberford road to what now appears to be a Holiday Inn, where I lived for a couple of years. That photo, I'm guessing, is from Pottery Lane looking South across Aberford Road? Pics from Google Maps - https://i.stack.imgur.com/4tM38.jpg & https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAB65.jpg

Comment: @BillyKerr - most Mac apps are like that. Some more complex ones use installers (I'm looking at you, Adobe;) but most don't; they're just drag & drop

Comment: @Tetsujin - yeah, it's almost the opposite situation in Windows generally, most programs have installers (which I hate). A few are just zips you need to extract (without having to install anything). All you do is run the .exe (or maybe create a shortcut to run it). Some programs like Inkscape have both an installer version and zip file version. One very good thing about Partha's portable GIMP for Windows, is you can extract the zip onto a memory stick, and run it direct from the memory stick. Not going to happen with Adobe applications!!!

Comment: @BillyKerr - for sure.  I used to run support for an online game so had to keep both versions around. Windows install, watching it copying over what felt like a million weeny files, 5 minutes or more of unreliable 'thermometer' display with names whizzing by unreadably fast. Mac install, drag & drop, 5 seconds. ;)

Comment: I was about to say that couldn't necessarily be done, when Tetsujin's Answer proved the point, in spades.

For most Users in most cases at least one of Tetsujin's examples will be successful beyond the wildest dream.

Even so, for the pedantic perfectionist, it can't be done.

Personally, I'd be more than happy with Tetsujin!